# Can I have an Any in a linq query?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to get an ID from a collection with a bool to tell me if that ID is associated with another value.

So, I have this:

```
public class RoleAssignment
{
    [Key]
    public int RoleAssignmentId { get; set; }

    public Guid AssigneeId { get; set; }

    public int RoleId { get; set; }
}
```

With this data:

```
var rAssnd = new List<RoleAssignment>{
    { 2, 0251F0D6-F2C9-E511-8C3C-00215E466552, 48 }
    { 3, 0251F0D6-F2C9-E511-8C3C-00215E466552, 49 }
    { 4, 0251F0D6-F2C9-E511-8C3C-00215E466552, 52 }
    { 5, F48459F5-469F-E511-8172-00215E466552, 44 }
}
```

So, if I am checking for RoleId 49, I would like to get a result set like this:

```
0251F0D6-F2C9-E511-8C3C-00215E466552, true
F48459F5-469F-E511-8172-00215E466552, false
```

Right now I'm trying this:

```
var results = selected.GroupBy (s => s.AssigneeId, s => s.RoleId == proposalRole);
```

But this gives me the Guid and a list.

Could I have the second value be something like `Any(s.RoleId == proposalRole)`?

Comment: How would you associate `F48459F5-469F-E511-8172-00215E466552` with RoleId `49` ? there is no relation between these two

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First group, then use any to check each group for your rule.

```
var results = rAssnd
    .GroupBy(s => s.AssigneeId)
    .Select(g => new
    {
        g.Key,
        hasRule = g.Any(s => s.RoleId == proposalRole)
    });
```

Comment: You might want to add another check for `hasRule`, i.e. to Check if `g.Count > 1 && g.Any(s => s.RoleId == proposalRole)` Not sure though, the current query with current data should work.